# Image appears broken in HTML

Tags: html, css, image, frontend

I am very new to html and css. I am trying to include an image in a project.

The **html file** has the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title> AirTable GUI For Arcade </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <h1> GUI Test </h1>
    </header>

    <img src="full_recycle_bin-512.png"/>
  </body>

</html>
```

The image file **full_recycle_bin-512.png** is in the same folder as the html file itself so I shouldn't have to use the full path for the image but, even with the full path, the image won't appear. When I run the project with ngrok, I only get the broken image icon. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try compressing the image using something like https://tinypng.com/

Comment: There's nothing wrong in the code you posted, the problem must be caused by something else

Comment: I'd check the file name and extension one last time just to make sure ;)

Comment: Does the image load correctly if you try to open it directly in the browser?

Comment: @DanielBeck hi Daniel, yeah, it does if I right-click on the file and then just ask to open it, the image loads, but not when I try to host it with ngrok (which to the best of my understanding should work the same?)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to right click on the broken image and copy the image address, so that you can know if the image path is correct.